# Angular' BuilderContext.reportStatus doesn't seem to report anything to console

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-builder

According to the angular-cli documentation `BuilderContext.reportStatus()` should be used to report status of the builder's activity, but I see nothing (using `"@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.802.0"`), while `BuilderContext.logger.info()` does, indeed, output status to a console, so I'm totally confused on how to use reportStatus feature.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm experiencing the same issue. And not sure why console output is empty while using reportProgress or reportStatus.